# how to pass an argument to the main method in java, which will be a word

Tags: java, netbeans, terminal, argument-passing

```
public class EcrireArguments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++)   
            System.out.println(args[i]);

        System.out.println(); // pour sauter une ligne
    }

}
```

but the problem is I run the program in the terminal, and it gives me an error

this was my command in terminal

```
java file_name word1 word2
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EcrireArguments (wrong name: ecrirearguments/EcrireArguments)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: Generally `java file_name word1 word2` should work. Can you [edit] your question and add more informations about how *precisely* you run your code, like location where your class is placed, location of terminal, precise command you used?

Comment: I suspect that something like `java -cp ecrirearguments EcrireArguments word1 word2` could work, but it depends on few assumptions based on location of console and location of `EcrireArguments.class` file.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't running the program in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, EcrireArguments.java is located in e:\java

Note: i assumed you already setup JAVA_HOME

1. open command prompt
2. cd into e:\java
3. set your classpath to current directory
4. verify your classpath
5. issue **javac EcrireArguments.java**
6. issue **java EcrireArguments word1 word2**

[image: java-basic-compile-and-run]
if you want to add to existing classpath use **set classpath=%classpath%;.;**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by adding my arguments in NetBeans: properties -> Run -> Arguments : word1 word2 
and it's OK!